# Xsl-transformation with grouping, getting ancestor property value

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to do an XSL-transform of an XML file to get a
[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdmDF.png)
and display the start time and the name of the program grouping by date.

This is my XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="m24_tv_style.xsl"?>
 <tv generator-info-name="Generator/0.01" generator-info-url="http://xmltv.s-tv.ru">
    <channel id="MOSCOW-24s">
       <display-name lang="ru">МОСКВА-24 (сайт)</display-name>
    </channel>
    <programme start="20181001060000 +0400" channel="MOSCOW-24s">
      <title lang="ru">УТРЕННЕЕ ВЕЩАНИЕ</title>

      <date>2018-10-01</date>
      <video></video>
      <category lang="ru">Инфо</category>
    </programme>
    <programme start="20181001100000 +0400" channel="MOSCOW-24s">
      <title lang="ru">НОВОСТИ<icon class='YhYho'></icon></title>

      <date>2018-10-01</date>
      <video></video>
      <category lang="ru">Инфо</category>
    </programme>
    <programme start="20181001101500 +0400" channel="MOSCOW-24s">
      <title lang="ru">СПЕЦИАЛЬНЫЙ РЕПОРТАЖ. ДОМ СВЯЗИ 12+</title>

      <date>2018-10-01</date>
      <video></video>
      <category lang="ru">Инфо</category>
    </programme>
    <programme start="20181001103500 +0400" channel="MOSCOW-24s">
      <title lang="ru">СПЕЦИАЛЬНЫЙ РЕПОРТАЖ КРУПНАЯ РЫБА 12+</title>

      <date>2018-10-02</date>
      <video></video>
      <category lang="ru">Инфо</category>
    </programme>
    <programme start="20181001110000 +0400" channel="MOSCOW-24s">
      <title lang="ru">НОВОСТИ<icon class='YhYho'></icon></title>

      <date>2018-10-02</date>
      <video></video>
      <category lang="ru">Инфо</category>
    </programme>
    <programme start="20181001113000 +0400" channel="MOSCOW-24s">
      <title lang="ru">КЛИМАТ-КОНТРОЛЬ 12+</title>

      <date>2018-10-02</date>
      <video></video>
      <category lang="ru">Инфо</category>
    </programme>
    <programme start="20181001114500 +0400" channel="MOSCOW-24s">
      <title lang="ru">НОВОСТИ<icon class='YhYho'></icon></title>

      <date>2018-10-03</date>
      <video></video>
      <category lang="ru">Инфо</category>
    </programme>
    <programme start="20181001120000 +0400" channel="MOSCOW-24s">
      <title lang="ru">НОВОСТИ<icon class='YhYho'></icon></title>

      <date>2018-10-03</date>
      <video></video>
      <category lang="ru">Инфо</category>
    </programme>
    <programme start="20181001123000 +0400" channel="MOSCOW-24s">
      <title lang="ru">НОВОСТИ<icon class='YhYho'></icon></title>

      <date>2018-10-03</date>
      <video></video>
      <category lang="ru">Инфо</category>
    </programme>
```

This is my XSL-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="newline">
  <xsl:text>
  </xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="dates" match="programme" use="date"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//programme[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('dates', date)[1])]">

      <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('dates', date)">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I group by date and display the names of the programs:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROQAu.png)

How can I get the start time of a program?
Maybe there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: Your XSLT does NOT "get a table structure". It produces a plain text list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:key name="pgm-by-date" match="programme" use="date"/>

<xsl:template match="/tv">
    <xsl:for-each select="programme[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('pgm-by-date', date)[1])]">
        <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('pgm-by-date', date)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(@start, 9, 2)"/>
            <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(@start, 11, 2)"/>
            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

This is assuming that the programs are already sorted chronologically.